# What is the shortest duration Vibrator.vibrate() can be called with where the device will still vibrate?

Tags: android, android-vibration

- 100 milliseconds works, but was too long of a vibration for my requirement.
- 50 milliseconds works and gives me what I want
- 10 milliseconds didn't work on my device

This made me curious, is there a guarantee that 50ms will work on all devices?  Is there a way to determine the vibrator's spec programmatically and set the vibration duration accordingly?  Or possibly a way to tell that the vibrator vibrated at all.

Comment: No, the only guarantee I can give you is that 50 ms will not work on all devices. Devices don't all have the same vibration motors, and some devices don't have any whatsoever.

Comment: For more control over vibrations, I'd suggest you take a look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.immersion.EffectPreview Immersion makes the vibration hardware motors/actuators for most of the phones in the world. Their api gives you more granular control over vibrations and it will even work for vibration motors that they didn't make themselves. But again, there is no guarantee that a particular small duration will work everywhere, that's just something you have to test for yourself with a couple of different devices, and make an educated compromise.

Comment: Also asked on Android.SE: [Minimal working vibration time on all Android devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250848/44325)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) for the vibrator.

It actually lets you check if your device [has a vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#hasVibrator()) with

```
hasVibrator()
```

But that's about it. It won't tell you if you give it a vibrate duration that isn't long enough.

Comment: Thanks Stephan.  Appreciate the help.  I'm already using hasVibrator().  Is there maybe a number that most developers are using with good success across most devices?  Maybe 100ms?  If I can guarantee 80-90% of the top 10 Android devices will vibrate, i'd settle for that.  Vibrate happening isn't mission critical, just a nicety.